# Making a JList in netbeans Frame

Tags: java, swing, jlist, layout-manager

i'm making an Jlist in Netbeans and i have written a code but the code dissapears not in my Jlist

```
/** Creates new form Toetsenbordd */
    public Toetsenbordd() {
       initComponents();
        initCustomComponents();
    }

    private void initCustomComponents(){
     JList Lijstje;
     JScrollPane Lijst; 

         String filename[]= {"Ard ","Astronauts",
            "Behind the Scene Movie credits","DNA Research -- the Human Genome Project",
            "Extract from The Adventures of Pinocchio","History of Photography",
            "Hubble Space Telescope","Legends of Abraham Lincoln","Netiquette",
            "Observations of the Father of Computing (1791 - 1871)","Rules of Baseball (from 1889)",
            "Speeding up the strategy process","Stinging Insects","The Eight Tools for Creating New Values",
            "The Life of Calamity Jane","The Little Match Girl (adapted)","The Tail of Peter Rabbit",
            "Thoughts of Banjamin Franklin","What is the Cast","Yosemite National Park"
            };
        {

          Lijstje = new JList(filename);
          Lijstje.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,15));
        Lijst =new JScrollPane(Lijstje);
        Lijst.setSize(410,200);
        Lijst.setLocation(70,75);
        Lijstje.setVisibleRowCount(6);
        Lijstje.setSelectedIndex(0);
        Lijstje.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        //seting the border for filescroll
        Lijst.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("CHOOSE TEST"));

        add(Lijst);

    }     



    }
```

It stands in the middle of my selfmade Jframe:

[image]

But i want it there where it says item 1,2,3

Comment: your question isn't clear for me are you talking about how to layout yor two JList???

Comment: what is Toetsenbordd ? which class does it extend

Comment: the Jlist in the middle with the titles is the one who doesn't belong there this belongs in the Jlist down, item 1 must Stinging insects by example and toetsenbordd is the name of my Jframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all please don't start your variable names with capital letters, this is against the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

`setLocation` in your code implies that you want your `Lijst` to have an absolute position. This is only possible when you are not using a LayoutManager, refer to [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html). To do that you need to set layout manager to `null` explicitly because `BorderLayout` is the default:

```
setLayout(null)
```

But it's not recommended to go with a `null` layout manager, and you really should consider using the one from the [list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)